# T-SQL split table vertically (moving column) with (almost) same performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, view, refactoring

In T-SQL (MS SQL Server 2016) I want to split vertically a big table (220 GB - 500 million rows) as some columns data are descriptions and some are daily data.

So from

```
CREATE TABLE [BigTable](
    [OptionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [char](255) NOT NULL,
    [Price] [real] NULL,
    [PriceTheo] [real] NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_BigTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ParentID] ASC,
    [Date] ASC,
    [OptionID] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I would move to:

```
CREATE TABLE [DescriptionTable](
    [OptionVersionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [OptionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [char](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DescriptionTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([OptionVersionID] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [DailyTable](
    [OptionVersionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Price] [real] NULL,
    [PriceTheo] [real] NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_DailyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([OptionVersionID] ASC,[Date] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DailyTable_Date] ON [DailyTable]
([Date] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DailyTable_OptionVersionID] ON [DailyTable]
([OptionVersionID] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [DailyTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DailyTable_DescriptionTable] FOREIGN KEY([OptionVersionID])
REFERENCES [DescriptionTable] ([OptionVersionID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [DailyTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DailyTable_DescriptionTable]
GO
```

I then create a view

```
CREATE VIEW [vBigTable]
AS
SELECT 
  [OptionID],
  [Date],
  [ParentID],
  [Description],
  [Price],
  [PriceTheo] 
FROM DailyTable da INNER JOIN
  DescriptionTable de ON da.OptionVersionID = de.OptionVersionID
```

I thought I should get the same kind of performance (almost) when I request data from the view vBigTable but actually I don't (some request can be 10x slower). Do I miss something to have almost the same performance when I select, join, group by ... (only reading data) from vBigTable or even when I use the specific INNER JOIN between Description and Daily table?

PS: I have more non clustered indices and columns in real life.

Comment: Depending on your query, you might want to make the `VIEW` schema bound, and then you can add indexes to the `VIEW` as well.

Comment: How many records are in DescriptionTable?  I hope a lot fewer than 500 million.

Comment: Can you provide the CPU time and logical reads to compare? 10x slower might be from physical reads. Does all this fit in cache?

Comment: I have "only" 6 million rows in DescriptionTable